# Animate Single item on flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

How i can animate a single item from flatlist ?

I tryed adding a value to isolate the selected record but didnt' work,maybe i wrote something wrong. Atm the animation is on ALL records

Flatlist:

```
 <View style={style.container}>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.ReturnedArray}
                    width='100%'
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}
                    renderItem={this.renderizza}>
```

Render Flalist :

```
renderizza = (item) => {
        var str = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item.item.itemType)).name + ' ' + JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item.item.itemType)).cognome
        let acronym = str.split(/\s/).reduce((response, word) => response += word.slice(0, 1), '')
        return (
            <View style={style.containerFlat}>
                <View style={style.containerFlat1}>    
                    <Text style={style.txt}>{JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item.item.itemType)).name} {JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item.item.itemType)).cognome}</Text>
                </View>
               <TouchableOpacity style={style.containerFlat2} onPress={() => this.badge(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item.item.itemType)).expoToken)}> 
                    <Animated.View style={[style.animatedView, { opacity: this.state.fadeValue}]}><Text>ADDED</Text></Animated.View>
                    <Text style={style.AvatarTxt}  >{acronym}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
```

And here the animation :

```
    badge(chiavi) {
        console.log(chiavi)
        if ((this.state.SelectedUser).includes(chiavi)) {
            this.state.SelectedUser.splice(this.state.SelectedUser.indexOf(chiavi), 1)
            Animated.timing(this.state.fadeValue, {
                toValue: 0,
                duration: 0
            }).start();
        } else {
            this.state.SelectedUser.push(chiavi)
            Animated.timing(this.state.fadeValue, {
                toValue: 1,
                duration: 0
            }).start()
        }
    }
```

Hot to fix ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to maintain an active item in the state and use `extraData` prop for this variable in `Flatlist`.Then conditionally render between the Animated and normal Item.

```
animate = index => {
    this.setState({
      activeItem: index,
    });
     //Rest of animation code.
  };

<TouchableOpacity onPress={e => this.animate(index)}>
   {this.state.activeItem === index && (
      <Animated.View
         style={[
                styles.button,
                { transform: [{ scale: this.animationMap }] },
                ]}
      >
        <Text>{item.title}</Text>
      </Animated.View>
      )
   }
   {this.state.activeItem !== index && (
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Text>{item.title}</Text>
          </View>
        )
   }
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

Here is an sample [Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@karthik.01/renderitem-animation)

Comment: I hope you understood it clearly,since i didn't add any comments.

Comment: Unfortunally this work by a single item.I need for a multiple selection.Will look around

Comment: Though to understand how to adapt to my code , but nothing. Mind can u help with my code ?
At event , Onpress , i add the token into an array and delete if already preset. Thank you